# JavaScript, setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

Код:

```
var first = 0;
var second = 0;
var sub = 0;
function subtractionFunction() {
    document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('timerSubtraction').innerHTML = "";
    first = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    second = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    sub = parseInt(first-second);
    document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += first;
    document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += " ";
    document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += '-';
    document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += " ";
    document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += second;
    document.getElementById('timerSubtraction').innerHTML = first + Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
}

function timerSubtraction() {
    var obj = document.getElementById('timerSubtraction');
    obj.innerHTML--;

    if (obj.innerHTML < sub) {
        return subtractionFunction();
    } else {
        setTimeout(timerSubtraction, 1000);
    }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="subtractionFunction(); timerSubtraction()"> Click </div>

<div id="example"></div>

<div id="timerSubtraction"></div>
```

И проблема вот здесь:

```
if (obj.innerHTML < sub) {return subtractionFunction();}
```

Как снова вызвать эти две функции при таком раскладе. 
Пробовала вызвать `subtractionFunction`, вызывая в ней при этом `timerSubtraction`, но не выходит, потому что число уменьшается с шагом в .
Как это исправить?

Comment: Вам надо timerSubtraction() вызывать каждую секунду?

Comment: @Skywave да. Уменьшение числа каждую секунду.

Comment: можно вынести setTimeout из timerSubtraction и объявить setInterval вне

Comment: @Skywave, простите, но в setTimeout и setInterval я не очень сильно разбираюсь, но точно знаю, что это две разные функции, так ведь? Разве здесь не подходит только setTimeout?

Comment: они разные только тем, что setTimeout() выполняет функцию один раз через указанное кол-во времени, а setInterval() выполняет функцию каждые N мс.

Comment: На вопрос конечно ответили, но все же
`document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += first;
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += " ";
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += '-';
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += " ";
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += second;`
чудовищно плохая идея. Используйте `document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = first.toString() + " - " + second.toString()`

Comment: @Vasiliy Rusin  спасибо, буду знать)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В этом примере можно просто вызывать функцию, отвечающую за таймер, внутри subtractionFunction();

```
var first = 0;
var second = 0;
var sub = 0;

function subtractionFunction() {
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML = "";
  document.getElementById('timerSubtraction').innerHTML = "";
  first = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  second = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
  sub = parseInt(first - second);
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += first;
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += " ";
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += '-';
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += " ";
  document.getElementById('example').innerHTML += second;
  document.getElementById('timerSubtraction').innerHTML = first + Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
  timerSubtraction();
}

function timerSubtraction() {
  var obj = document.getElementById('timerSubtraction');
  obj.innerHTML--;

  if (obj.innerHTML < sub) {
    return subtractionFunction();
  } else {
    setTimeout(timerSubtraction, 1000);
  }
}
```

А в диве вызывать только одну функцию:

```
<div onclick="subtractionFunction(); timerSubtraction()"> Click </div>

<div id="example"></div>

<div id="timerSubtraction"></div>
```

Вот ссылка на https://jsfiddle.net/1vayrdyg/

Сам пример немного странный, но с его помощью, надеюсь, удалось объяснить что нужно сделать.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, он, в общем-то, подходит, но есть одна проблема: при верном ответе таймер ускоряется. Наглядно это можно увидеть здесь: http://kurusa.zhecky.net/lesson_11/.